# Detect thin line in an image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm having a hard time detecting the thin black line in the following image. I tried all sort of opencv processing and applied findContours, but wasn't able to catch this. Is anyone able to help plz?

For example I tried this:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('SampleLine.png')
# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, thresh_type, block, constant)
 # apply morphology open then close
 kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1,1))
 blob = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
 kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10,10))
 blob = cv2.morphologyEx(blob, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
 # invert blob
 blob = (255 - blob)
 cnts,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blob, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
 cv2.imwrite("output_Line.png", img)
```

[image]

I'm looking for an output like this:

[image]

Comment: An idea is: 1) Load image, grayscale, then Otsus' or adaptive threshold. At this point you will have a binary image with the lines in fragments but we need to get a single contour so next you can 2) dilate or morph close with a vertical kernel. Finally 3) find contours and filter using aspect ratio to isolate the line. An alternative to this finding contour step would be to just detect vertical lines using morph open and a vertical kernel.

Comment: don't binarize, don't apply any morphology operations, don't use any findContours. -- instead: convert to grayscale. sum/average every column of pixels. plot the resulting values. (maybe calculate the derivative.) find extrema.